# making user field visible depending on the group a user belongs to

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

There is an app where teachers can register lessons they have with individual pupils. If a teacher adds a new lesson then he is automatically registered as a teacher who taught this lesson. So in a form there is no such a field as 'Teacher' because the `request.user` is used for this data.

But I also would like an administrator to register a lesson for a teacher. Then this form should have a 'Teacher' field as well. What is the right way to do it?

in `models.py`:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    pupil = models.ForeignKey(Pupil, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey("auth.User",
                                limit_choices_to={'groups__name': "teachers"})
```

in `views.py`:

```
class LessonCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView, ):
    model = Lesson
    fields = ['pupil', 'subject', ]
    permission_required = 'foreigntest.add_lesson'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.teacher = self.request.user
        obj.save()
```

so I guess I have to add `'Teacher'` to the fields list if the user belongs to admin types, right?

Comment: So you achieved what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the `Form` yourself for this one, this would allow you to override the fields based on the user.

forms.py

```
class LessonCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ['pupil', 'subject', 'teacher']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(LessonCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # This is the special part - we leave the teacher field in by default
        # When the form is created, we check the user and see if they are an admin
        # If not, remove the field.
        if not user.is_admin:
            self.fields.pop('teacher')
```

When you create the form in `views.py`, you need to pass in the user kwarg:

```
class LessonCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView, ):
    model = Lesson
    fields = ['pupil', 'subject', ]
    permission_required = 'foreigntest.add_lesson'
    form_class = LessonCreateForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(UserFormKwargsMixin, self).get_form_kwargs()
        # Update the existing form kwargs dict with the request's user.
        kwargs.update({"user": self.request.user})
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.teacher = self.request.user
        obj.save()
```

I took `get_form_kwargs()` straight from [django-braces](https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form.html#userformkwargsmixin) which I highly recommend - you can just add `UserFormKwargsMixin` to your view, and `UserKwargModelFormMixin` to your form, and you skip all the poping of the user.